# Why does return true or false and break; doesnt work?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in C# and have this code, don't know why I get these errors:

> Main.cs(28,22): error CS0031: Constant value `true' cannot be converted to an` int'
> Main.cs(41,14): error CS0031: Constant value `false' cannot be converted to an` int'

I just need to return true or false and stop the execution of the program in case its true.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

class MainClass 
{
    public static int SumMultiplier(int[] arr) 
    {
        int sum = arr.Sum();
        int doubleValue = sum * 2;
        int totalElements = arr.Count(); 
        // Console.WriteLine("doble "+doubleValue);
        // Console.WriteLine(totalElements);
        // int j = totalElements;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            if(i + 1 < totalElements)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("sds"+arr[i]*arr[i+1]);
                for (int j = 0; j < totalElements; j++)
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine("numero iteracion "+i+" multiplica "+arr[i]+" por "+arr[j]);
                    int multRes = arr[j] * arr[i];

                    if(multRes > doubleValue)
                    {
                        return true;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    
        // return condition;
        return false;
    }

    static void Main() 
    { 
        // keep this function call here
        Console.WriteLine(SumMultiplier(Console.ReadLine()));
    } 
}
```

Comment: `return true` tries to return `true` from the method.. while the method has `int` as return type. That's why you are seeing this error. You should return integer value from the method... `return <<somenumber>>`

Comment: You try to return a Boolean from a method that is defined to return an integer. And a `break` after a `return` is useless that's never reached anyway.

Comment: go through each section of this course
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/

Comment: A C programmer? C doesn't really have `bool` type, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are just `int`s. C# does have a bool type, but does not have an implicit conversion from `bool` to `int` (or vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your return type in **SumMultiplier** to bool (boolean type)

```
public static bool SumMultiplier(int[] arr) {
   
    int sum = arr.Sum();
    int doubleValue = sum*2;
    int totalElements = arr.Count(); 
    //Console.WriteLine("doble "+doubleValue);
    //Console.WriteLine(totalElements);
    //int j = totalElements;
    for (int i=0; i<totalElements;i++){
      
      //Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
      if(i+1<totalElements){
        //Console.WriteLine("sds"+arr[i]*arr[i+1]);
          for (int j=0; j<totalElements;j++){
            
            //Console.WriteLine("numero iteracion "+i+" multiplica "+arr[i]+" por "+arr[j]);
            
            int multRes = arr[j]*arr[i];
            

            if(multRes>doubleValue){
              return true;
              break;
            } 

          }
      

      }

    }

    
    //return condition;
      return false;
  }
```